# Сотни ответов на ruSO? Почему бы и не написать книгу?

Tags: обсуждение

Вопрос(ы), может быть не совсем по части ruSO, но напрямую с ним связан(ы) и суть его(их) заключается в следующем.

Здесь можно найти очень много опытных пользователей, которые за время своего пребывания на сайте написали такое количество полезной текстовой информации, что невольно возникает вопрос: не хотят ли такие пользователи пойти дальше и написать книгу о том, в чём они здесь хороши? Ведь очевидно же, что недостатка текстовых знаний в перерасчёте на книжный лист у них не бывает, ибо на книгу в 250-350 стр они наберут из первой сотни своих ответов. Значит, есть другая причина, какая?

Вот например, на Западе, среди профессионалов, очень распространено написание книг о роде своей деятельности. У нас пока такого распространения писательства пока не получило. Как думаете, с чём это связано?

В общем, подытоживая, хотелось бы услышать ваши размышления на тему этих вопросов и что с этим можно сделать. Как подспорье можно попробовать для себя ответить на такую небольшую анкету:

- Хотите ли вы написать книгу?
- О чём она могла бы быть?
- Что вам мешает, какие сложности вас наиболее пугают?
- Почему, по вашему мнению, написание книг не распространено в России?
- Как можно улучшить положение вещей по данному вопросу?

В целом, вопрос можно было бы закрыть "Как слишком общий", но всё же, думается, для всего сообщества было бы полезнее поразмышлять над ним.

## Дополнение

Сводка упомянутых в обсуждениях (и не только) доводов за и против.

**Доводы за**

- Просто нравится делиться знаниями.
- Тешит самолюбие, приносит известность.
- Повышается востребованность, твоя "стоимость" на рынке растёт как знатока (специалиста).
- Улучшается понимание вопроса за счёт погружения в него и упорядочивания знаний.
- Книга может быть востребована по ряду причин:

  - об этом мало или почти ничего не пишут.
- Вы уже написали ни один десяток "книг" в виде кода, который пишете по частям (страницам) или в виде ответов на RUso, так что общее понимание о создании у у вас, как разработчиков, уже имеется.
- Можно начать с малого со своего дневника (блога) или страничника (сайта) посвященному вопросам, который хотите осветить в своей книге. Таким образом ко времени её выхода в свет о вас уже будут иметь представления как о сведущем человеке.
- Если по вашему мнению, нахождение книги в открытом доступе вредит вам, то сейчас имеются законные средства борьбы с этим.
- Если денежный вопрос для вас не важен, то написанную книгу можно самому выложить в открытый доступ, не тратя время на переговоры с издательствами.
- Если важен, то её также можно продавать в Сети в электронном виде.
- Возможно тебя поддержут с помощью пожертвований, если книга будет в открытом доступе.
- На основе работы по созданию книги можно будет рассматривать создание своего
  дела:

  - обучение в Сети.
  - обучение организаций (привет RedHat).
- Многие известные в той или иной области знатоки своего дела писали книги (работы) о своей деятельности.

**Доводы против**

- Её может быть сложно продать, по ряду причин:

  - высокая цена;
  - выложут в открытый доступ в Сеть;
  - небольшой выпуск (тираж);
  - недостаток продвижения (рекламы).
- Требует много времени.
- Низкая покупательная способность у читателей.
- Писателю, особенно начинающему, достаются крохи от продаж.
- Возможно мало желающих прочитать твоё творение.
- Зачем писать, если всё можно найти в Сети, почти бесплатно.
- Рынок сбыта среди русскоязычных меньше, чем среди англоязычных стран (можно перевести).
- Некоторые вопросы сложно описать, проще показать (привет YouTube).
- Соперничество среди писателей (конкуренция).
- Написанная книга может устареть к выходу в свет в связи с быстро меняющейся отраслью.

Comment: Хотелось бы заслушать н̵а̵ч̵а̵л̵ь̵н̵и̵к̵а̵ ̵т̵р̵а̵н̵с̵п̵о̵р̵т̵н̵о̵г̵о̵ ̵ц̵е̵х̵а̵  Сергея Теплякова. Это один из участников нашего сайта и он написал книгу по паттернам проектирования.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не так уже [он](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178188/sergey-teplyakov) и активен тут...

Comment: Ответы на SO короткие, пишутся по настроению и направлены на решение конкретных вопросов. Книга же — это 1) большой объём текста, 2) длительная непрерывная работа, 3) имеет широкую направленность, которую надо выдумать и проработать.

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущего оратора. У меня уже полгода лежит серия недооформленных статей на Хабр, которая может потянуть на формат _Little Book_. Это требует времени больше, чем пару-тройку раз в день по 5 минут, как ответы на SO.

Answer (score 14):

> Хотите ли вы написать книгу?

Да, хотел бы. Мне нравится делиться и обмениваться с другими людьми  знаниями.

> О чём она могла бы быть?

- Применение SVG в современном веб дизайне HTML страниц
- Взаимодействие SVG c CSS и Javascript
- SVG анимация: теория и практические примеры

Думаю была бы востребована, так как за рубежом очень мало книг на эту тему, а у нас в России вообще нет. 
По сайтам, посвященным SVG кочует одни и те же немногочисленные переводы. 
Правда недавно на Хабре появилась хорошая статья по анимации -  [Все об SVG анимации](https://habr.com/ru/post/450924/), но в книге это можно было бы сделать более интересно и развернуто.

> Почему, по вашему мнению, написание книг не распространено в России?

У нас очень любят читать и компьютерную литературу тоже. Помните были времена, когда все книжные магазины, даже самые затрапезные ларьки были забиты журналами, книгами по компьютерной тематике.
Теперь такого бума нет, потому что в интернете можно найти абсолютно бесплатно электронные копии всей литературы. Да и бумажные экземпляры стоят очень дорого и тиражи с реализацией резко упали. 
Поэтому упал интерес у людей к писательскому ремеслу.

> Что вам мешает, какие сложности вас наиболее пугают?

Написание хорошей книги займет, как минимум полгода плотного труда.  После продажи нескольких экземпляров в электронном виде, она  через несколько дней, будет размещена в свободном доступе,   на всех популярных трекерах.

Если выпустить только бумажный экземпляр, то это надо делать за свой счет  малым тиражом и всё равно книгу отсканируют  и выложат на трекеры.

Так будет ли стоить овчинка затраченного труда и времени :-)

Update

Я давно думаю стоит или не стоит заняться написанием, чего-нибудь более объемного, чем написание развернутых ответов на ruSO, но каждый раз суровая действительность возвращает на землю,- надо кормить семью и в первую очередь заниматься тем, что это обеспечивает.

Comment: Дельно написано. В СНГ реально много сложностей из-за того что люди элементарно привыкли к халяве и чужой интелектуальный труд особо не ценят. Даже если цена книги будет низкой, что-то вроде 1$, это особо не остановит сканерокопиров.

Comment: По Inkscape также книгу можно написать, нет нормальной на русском языке.

Comment: @ L.F.C. Я уверен наш народ нисколько не хуже западной публики, но почему на западе привыкли платить, а у нас нет? Потому что покупательная способность рубля очень низкая. Стандартная цена за подобную литературу от 19.99$ до 99.99$, то есть 100 американских рублей превращаются у нас в 6.500 рублей, а это согласитесь очень накладно платить. Им проще отдать свои 100 американских рублей

Comment: @L.F.C. Пиратство тут не причём. [Фабьен Санглард](http://fabiensanglard.net/gebbdoom/index.html) и [Сергей Абдульманов](https://habr.com/ru/company/mosigra/blog/455306/) писали о своём опыте публикации книг (через Амазон и МИФ соответственно). И там и там автору перепадают копейки.

Comment: @ߊߚߤߘ тут быстрее не про пиратство как таковое, а про менталитет ряда людей.

Comment: Вариант: 1) написать книгу => сделать для  нее сайт => монетезировать просмотры через показ рекламы 2) Договориться с издательством на продажу прав на книгу => все отсальное проблемы издательства . Но возможно, это только мои фантазии

Comment: Сделать нормальный сайт, где публиковать объёмные статьи... и вообще создать хорошую документацию по SVG, со всеми подробностями и прочее....  Сайт выходит на монетизацию, а если на сайте всё будет хорошо и удобно, то люди будут приходить. А там можно уже и книгу сделать. Если сайт будет реально полезен, то вы как его создатель и главный автор уже имеете авторитет, поэтому успех книги может быть уже обеспечен в какой-то степени.

Comment: Поддерживаю! Очень полезная идея. Сейчас обучение проходит самостоятельно. Хотелось бы также в книге увидеть статистику по нагрузке от SVG анимаций, сравнение с другими видами анимаций.

Если говорить касательно авторского права - мой знакомый выпустил электронную книгу в продажу год назад, но до сих пор её никто не слил

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, это неправильный буржуйский подход продавать знания в книгах, да ещё и через издательства. Знания должны быть безплатны. Лучше раздавай книгу в электронном виде безплатно за добровольные пожертвования. А тех, кто желает бумажную книгу записывай в очередь через э-майл. Когда их соберётся определённое кол-во человек, то закажи определённое кол-во книг и продай их. Как-то я читал про музыкантов, которые безплатно раздавали компакт-диски и получили в итоге гораздо больше от пожертвований. Но статью не смог найти.

Comment: @Bharata как ты предлагаешь делают очень многие и согласен, правильно делают и получают в итоге намного больше. Самый яркий пример - `Уральские пельмени` они сами выкладывают всё на Youtube и не гоняются с палкой за другими, кто выкладывает их концерты. Поэтому они мегапопулярны. и получают хорошие доходы. Но это не мой случай... у меня и близко нет ихнего таланта и способностей :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, я всё-таки нашёл подобную статью https://habr.com/ru/post/404515/

Answer (score 11):

> Хотите ли вы написать книгу? О чём она могла бы быть?

Хочу, могу, пишу. Туториал по Oracle APEX. Ссылка в профиле. У меня встречный вопрос: а что, кто-то хочет поддержать моё начинание рублем (лучше евром, конечно ;))? Ссылка там же, чуть дальше. Но иллюзий у меня нет, конечно.

> Что вам мешает, какие сложности вас наиболее пугают?

Как вы наверное уже поняли, ничего не мешает, ничто не пугает.

> Почему, по вашему мнению, написание книг не распространено в России?

Элементарно, Ватсон: ВВП "русскоязычной экономической зоны" - это примерно 2% мирового ВВП против 40% с лишним англоговорящей среды (США, Британия и бывшие её колонии, ЕС), плюс русскоязычная зона - это сырьевая экономика с почти полным отсутствием высокотехнологического сектора, причем хайтек еще и потихоньку ползет в сторону ЕС/США (см. хотя бы пример братьев Бухманов).

> Как можно улучшить положение вещей по данному вопросу?

Изменить структуру ВВП и поднять его раз в 10. Тогда спрос на книги хоть как-то оторвется от плинтуса и покроет по крайней мере расходы на пиво летом и кофе зимой.

Comment: очень точный ответ. Я бы ещё дополнил. Количество жителей "русской цивилизации" в мире ~180 миллионов человек а количество жителей "западной цивилизации" в мире один миллиард человек.

Comment: Википедия утверждает, что порядка 300 миллионов владеют русским. Английским - почти полтора миллиарда.

Comment: я не верю википедии :3 , по тому что я также учтен в "владении английским языком" . Важно не сколько на  _вставьте язык_ говорят, а важно сколько на нём созидает (чертежи, документация, книги , сказки, и т.д.).

Comment: Для обсуждаемого тут вопроса (написание книг) - важно в первую очередь, сколько на нем читает. Во вторую очередь - что именно читает и сколько у них денег. Все остальное - мелочи.

Answer (score 4):

> Хотите ли вы написать книгу?

Скорее нет, чем да, хотя иногда посещают такие мысли.

> О чём она могла бы быть?

У меня 2 варианта

- Программирование графики для Web
- Математика для создания изображений

> Что вам мешает, какие сложности вас наиболее пугают?

Мешает и пугает все:

Я не умею писать понятно, структурировано.

Как всегда нет времени (лень)

Книга к сожалению хуже доносит информацию, чем например интерактивная визуализация: ни один напечатанный на бумаге график функции нельзя приблизить, поменять коэффициенты...

Книга про конкретную технологию рано или поздно перестает быть актуальной.

У меня не проходящее ощущение беспомощности по отношению к объему информации которую я хотел бы осмыслить в этих областях.

> Почему, по вашему мнению, написание книг не распространено в России?

Пишут и много, однако всякую ересь без идеи(души) или просто переводы. Пишут те кто хотят на этом заработать. И это понятно, выкручиваются как умеют.

PS: Если я когда нибудь и соберусь написать книгу, я постараюсь чтобы она не была скучной.

Например, выбрать тематику приемов и примеров кода в книге в виде визуализации персонажей русских народных сказок или анекдотов :) но это все находится только но уровне идей...

Comment: твою книгу про Математика для создания изображений я бы прочитал.Если бы было

Answer (score 2):

> Хотите ли вы написать книгу?

Делиться своим опытом я определенно хочу и более того: я постоянно это практикую.
Но вряд ли это имело бы формат книги...

> О чём она могла бы быть?

Если бы я писал книгу, то она посвящалась бы не техническим аспектам, а IT-бизнесу и менеджменту.

Найти информацию по техническим аспектам и разобраться с этим не так то уж и сложно.
С этим в России нет никаких проблем.
Мы одна из ведущих стран, по поставкам мяса в мировую IT-индустрию.

А вот менеджмент в России это полное дно.
И IT-бизнес в России это дикий запад.

Плюс данный опыт является и самым болезненным и эмоциональным.
Поэтому и мотивация делиться данным опытом является наибольшей.

> Что вам мешает, какие сложности вас наиболее пугают?

Мешает только время... точнее его постоянная нехватка или полное отсутствие.

> Почему, по вашему мнению, написание книг не распространено в России?

Написание книг в России очень даже распространено...одна только Дарья Данцова сколько книг написала? 
Если же говорить о технической литературе, то тут есть несколько проблем:

- № 1. Русскоязычное IT-коммьюнити не такое уж и большое, чтобы окупилось время на написание книги с нуля. Работая тоже время программистом, как правило, заработаешь больше. Исключение может составить php какой-нибудь... Если же речь идет о каких-то более высоких материях, то увы и ах... На них не такой большой спрос.
- № 2. Русскоязычное коммьюнити вторично по своей сути... все продукты, инструменты и пр. выпускаются как правило в мировое сообщество. А языком общения в данном мировом сообществе является - английский. Соответственно первичная документация, туториалы и прочая сопровождающая литература оригинально выпускаются на английском. И тебе нужно время на то чтобы освоить данный продукт и инструмент изучить всю документацию, туториалы, кейсы и прочие материалы на английском языке. Потом написать что-то оригинальное, но уже на русском... Пока ты ее закончишь выйдет уже новая версия, а возможно даже не одна...и все твои труды будут уже неактуальны... В далеком 2007 году я был таким же наивным и переводил документации к популярным программным продуктам/фреймворкам с английского на русский... еще тогда я понял всю бессмысленность этой затеи... Ты тратишь на это драгоценные килотонны своего времени, а воспользуются твоими трудами 2 калеки... и то в лучшем случае. Обидно делать работу, которую никто не видит и которая никому не нужна.

> Как можно улучшить положение вещей по данному вопросу?

Положение вещей не является каким-то "не таким".
Все в порядке своих вещей. 
Люди делятся своими знаниями и опытом.
Просто в 2К19 году для этой цели подходят не только книги.
Есть блоги, сообщества, хабр, стековерфлоу, форумы, youtube, конференции и прочее.
И нам грех жаловаться... я не видел никакой другой профессиональной отрасли с такой активностью в плане обмена опытом.
И с каждым годом активность только увеличивается.
Другое дело, что процент книг в данной деятельности всё уменьшается, но так и в общем, книги в плане распространения контента и информации уже давно уступили пальмы первенства журналам, телевидению и интернету... 
Так что в этом нет ничего сверхестественного.

Answer (score 1):

Читаю предыдущие ответы, и, как я понял, коллеги готовы поделиться знаниями, но не готовы (или не понимают) как эти знания монетизировать.

При чем здесь ВВП, 1$ и т.д.?

Не считаю себя хорошим программистом, но, ИМХО, написать даже не книгу, а некий "сборник советов" по известной мне области могу. Продавать этот "сборник" - не вижу смысла. Для продажи знаний есть профессии а-ля "IT-консультант".

Положение вещей можно решить такими "сборниками", которые выкладываются в свободной доступ (ну правда, кто на этапе написания условного диплома/курсовых etc. не использовал google/copy/paste?). А классифицированная информация помогла бы всем. Автору - как формализация знаний (это полезно любому человеку), а читателю - получение ответа не на конкретный вопрос "почему не работает...", а изучение background'а.

Comment: @edem, по идее, "IT-советник" должен вырасти из разработчика с бизнес-жилкой. Наверное, я живу в идеальном мире :)

Comment: Возможно, я буду ошибаться, но смысл такой работы очень похож на смысл написания документации: открытой, бесплатной и доступной. Даже без претенда на какую-либо монетизацию, чистый альтруизм. Это почти так же, как делать бесплатный софт без рекламы и воровства чего-либо

Comment: "При чем здесь ВВП, 1$ и т.д.?" - чем больше ВВП, тем больше зарплаты, тем проще расстаться с деньгами ради покупки книги. Плюс с ростом ВВП растет спрос на ИТ. Это настолько очевидно, что вообще непонятно, как такой вопрос может появиться.