# Ещё раз про [соревнования] и [code-golf]

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, правила, соревнование

История тянется уже давненько. Было и во время [Новогоднего конкурса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9961/15479).

Сейчас же подобная ситуации в этой теме: [Как анимировать слово StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1105132/15479).

Часть участников считает, что подобные вопросы слишком общие, поэтому не подпадают, к примеру, под разрешённые [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [code-golf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Тревоги на такие вопросы отнимают много сил модераторов. Тревоги вообще предназначены не для этого. Но вопрос на Мете, как я погляжу, так никто и не создал. Поэтому хочу уже раз и навсегда решить ситуацию с подобными вопросами.

Допустимы ли такие вопросы? Если да, то какие критерии/правила к формулировке заданий в таких вопросов должны быть?

Comment: Это не соревнование, так как у него нет каких-либо конкретных и объективно верных критериев, по которым собственно соревнуются. Это просто слишком общий вопрос вида «сделайте чё-нибудь».

Comment: @andreymal оформите подробным ответом, пожалуйста =/

Comment: @Grundy возможно пора пересмотреть. Почти 3 года прошло.

Comment: **StackOverflow** - это огромная уникальная база данных. В том числе и благодаря подобным вопросам и именно ответам к этим вопросам. И как показывает практика, подобные вопросы/ответы пользуются популярностью, а значит ценятся и для кого-то являются полезными. Кто-то хочет отломить кусок пирога у сообщества?

Comment: @Sevastopol' кто-то хочет **структурировать** этот кусок пирога, чтобы из бессвязного потока ответов получилось что-то, что действительно «вкусное» на практике и полезное многим людям в будущем. База данных без структуры — бесполезна. Вавилонская библиотека какая-то.

Comment: А зачем что-то пересматривать? Что изменилось за эти «почти 3 года» в плане гольфо-соревнований? Имхо, не надо идти по следам öбнуляторов сроков.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ в таком случае вопрос из поста закрыть надо.

Comment: Тут по сути не соревнование, так как никто не собирается определять победителя. Просто какой-то вопрос в свободной форме, вроде темы на форуме. А требования к соревнованиям можно и пересмотреть, так как они не работают. Никаких "шаблонов сниппетов" у нас нет.

Comment: В чем вообще проблема? В поисках ответа о подобную тему споткнуться нельзя. В топе висит, потому что людям нравится. О каком "загрязнении" базы данных воюет господин andreymal?

Comment: @hu-fo во-первых, очень даже можно наткнуться, потому что поисковики индексируют и тексты ответов тоже. Во-вторых, из-за того, что люди поленились разнести ответы по нормальным вопросам, эти полезные ответы «сгорают» в куче других ответов, и ищущие ответ на свой вопрос люди просто не смогут долистать до полезного им ответа. Это как свалить книги в библиотеке в одну кучу вместо расставления по полкам. Это загрязнение и вредительство. Ладно бы ненамеренное, если бы случайно в процессе какого-нибудь обсуждения появилось, так ведь нет, это **намеренное вредительство со сговором двух человек**.

Comment: @hu-fo SO - не форум. Вопросы должны удовлетворять критериям базы знаний. Для расширения тематики в своё время разрешили проводить соревнования, но там должен быть описан эталонный ответ/критерии и т.п. Вопросы, подобные вопросу из поста, под эти критерии не подпадают.

Comment: @andreymal Вы считаете, что вопросы типа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747622/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%8e-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83 С комментарием `Пишу сей вопрос в надежде, что кто-нибудь предложит вариант лучше найденного мной)` Чем то лучше данного вопроса?

Comment: @andreymal должны существовать только они. А ответы ребят в данной теме, не только добавляют понимание работы, добавляют новых идей и взглядов на реализацию, но и показывают по-настоящему "мастерство". Чего не скажешь ни обо мне, ни, увы, о Вас. Так что не Вам говорить о том, что эти темы не подходят. А по обсуждаемое сообщение не просто так набрало большое количество голосов. Потому что оно интересное и полезное. Отвечать на вопросы "Почему тут это не работает" - это посредственно. А задавать полезные вопросы как в указанной теме - принесёт ГОРАЗДО больше пользы.

Comment: @Denis640Kb конечно «вопросы типа» лучше, там описана конкретная практическая задача с внятным заголовоком и есть два чётких ответа, удовлетворяющих требованиям вопроса. Он не просто лучше — он эталон хорошего вопроса. Если вы считаете, что разные подходы к решению конретной задачи это плохо, то ересь здесь несёте вы.

Comment: @Denis640Kb «добавляют понимание работы» — вопрос называется не «как работают анимации svg», поэтому ваша ересь про «понимание работы» это ересь. А даже если бы вопрос назывался так, то ответы всё равно недостаточно подробно разъясняют принципы анимации, так что всё равно ересь. Ваши попытки защитить флудильню в базе знаний очень слабы и неумелы.

Comment: @Denis640Kb ТС в своём вопросе написал, что допускает **абсолютно любые** анимации — это НИКАК НЕЛЬЗЯ считать описанием задачи и вариантами решения.

Comment: @Denis640Kb сейчас с пеной у рта кричите вы, закрывая глаза на наличие фразы «абсолютно любые» и пытаясь защитить флудильню в базе знаний. Ваше «ОДИН В ОДИН похож на обсуждаемый» — это просто бред, я в своём вопросе описал конкретную задачу, какие линии мне нужно получить, и нигде никогда не просил продемонстрировать в ответах любые линии как угодно на вкус авторов ответов. Вы слепы и даже не удосужились внимательно прочитать мой вопрос.

Comment: @Denis640Kb прошу вас обоих не переходить на личности. Мы тут обсуждаем конкретный вопрос. Все эти "Вы слабый специалист", "Вас гложит зависть и глупое непонимание его сути" нарушает правила и вообще к сути вопроса никакого отношения не имеют. Если вы продолжите, мне придётся забанить вас. Обсуждайте предмет разговора, а не людей.

Comment: @andreymal я с вами вообще не согласен и не могу даже придумать ситуацию где человек ищущий варианты как анимировать текст, зайдя в подобную тему вынесет хоть какой-то негативный опыт...хотя могу...он увидит ваши комментарии. Кстати, где вы берете мотивацию на всё это? Ваших ответов по тегам js, svg, css, canvas и т.д я не видел, за то я вижу регулярно ответы тех, кто поучаствовал в конкурсе и постоянно учусь у них.

Comment: @hu-fo если вопрос — как анимировать текст, значит должен быть соответствующий заголовок, а в ответе должны быть описаны существующие методы анимации с описанием техник и границ применимости. И наверно такой вопрос всё равно окажется слишком общий, это вроде уже тянет на немаленькую статью, что опять же неформат для Stack Overflow. Ну а тупое вбрасывание примеров без пояснений никак не способствует качественному обучению. Человек, зайдя в подобную тему, не вынесет ничего кроме бездумного копипаста, потому что эта тема ничему не обучает. Делать такие темы в базе знаний плохо и неправильно.

Comment: @hu-fo вообще, для целей общего обучения будет намного, *намного* лучше, если Alexandr_TT [напишет книгу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9303). А Stack Overflow всё-таки немного не о том.

Comment: Как по мне такие вопросы ближе к подобным https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319846/winter-bash-2018-knitting, возможно вопросы, целью которых является развлечение членов сообщества,  больше подходят мете чем базе знаний?

Comment: @yolosora если попробовать применить опыт [диалогов-о-работе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5812), то «это попытка впихнуть на SO то, что должно быть на форумах» и «нельзя тащить на SO всё, к чему неравнодушно сообщество»

Comment: IMHO, некоторые защищают [tag:соревнование] и [tag:code-golf] только по той причине, что им весело. Такие вопросы "поднимают боевой дух" и удовлетворяют потребность в самовыражении. Но они объективно не подходят для базы знаний. Их невозможно загуглить, а решения представляют сомнительную пользу. Для таких вопросов нужен другой формат. И, увы, мы навряд ли сможем этот формат обеспечить.

Comment: @Denis640Kb если возможно ограничиться только предупреждением, то стоит ограничиться только предупреждением, а бан лучше оставить для слишком буйных. Suvitruf молодец и всё правильно делает (как он меня терпит вообще, удивительно)

Comment: @Andreymal по-этому я и говорю, что ни мои и ни Ваши ответы не могут быть полезными. За редким исключением. Что мне нравится - так это то, что Вы частно отвечаете на вопросы в комментариях, не ожидая похвалы, собственно как и я, но полезными ответы сложно называть. Так что говорю как есть. Если за это готовы забанить - да ради бога. Что касается вопросов и Alexandr_TT и StrangerInTheQ и Sevastopol` и Максима - я искренне считаю их потрясающими. Я сам лично очень многому научился у них. И КАЖДЫЙ вопрос добавляет знаний в мою копилку. Причём в большом количестве.

Comment: @Andreymal, А самое главное они пробуждают желание обучаться чему-то новому. Всё же backend не доставляет такого эстетического удовольствия, как визуальная часть. И Если они побуждают к новым знаниям или показывают новые методы реализации и эффектов - я считаю их полезными. Потому что, как минимум те, кто тут находится - сами обмениваются информацией и обучаются в других сферах, что не может никак быть минусом. Это побуждает получать больше знаний в разных сферах. И количество плюсов у вопроса показывает, что он полезен и важен другим.

Comment: @Denis640Kb к другим их вопросам (большинству) у меня нет никаких претензий, они все большие молодцы и пополняют базу знаний полезными и конкретными вещами. Меня не устраивает конкретно этот вопрос, который зачем-то по предварительному сговору решили превратить в свалку из слабо связанных примеров почти без пояснений, из которой нельзя вынести что-то действительно полезное вследствие её бесструктурности. Из такого вопроса можно вынести только копипаст и желание прочитать книгу про svg — это не то, для чего существует эта база знаний.

Comment: Как только на [сабже](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1105132/339283) оказалось 4 голоса за закрытие, на него повесили конкурс со странной формулировкой. IMHO, нехорошо, если учесть, что мы сейчас обсуждаем его легитимность...

Comment: @nomnoms12 Это скорее попытка наградить существующий ответ. Он не призывает к тому, чтобы ещё люди приняли в нём участие. Я сам вчера таким же образом пытался наградить ответ, который мне очень помог и восхитил. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1104084/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-svg-%d0%bd%d0%b0-css Выбирал - "Наградить существующий ответ". Но, почему-то ничего не вышло. А к текущему вопросу - если бы я мог, то я ещё бы добавил репутации в награду и от себя.

Comment: пускай frontend'ы  меряются своими достоинствами ..иногда прикольно понаблюдать особенно как @Sevastopol' на css делает то что обычно на js делают ...:))

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik и всё же мне по прежнему не нравится, что вы подняли тему про соревнования, в то время как обсуждаемый вопрос вообще не является соревнованием. Его бы переформулировать по-нормальному и переоткрыть.

Comment: @MaximLensky пускай frontend'ы меряются своими достоинствами в нормально оформленных соревнованиях с конкретными критериями, а не в туфте вида «слепите чё-нибудь».

Answer (score 3):

Мое мнение:

Такие вопросы закрывать *не* стоит. Потому что:

- Code-golf на русском еще не кто не создал и вряд ли создаст.
- Уже ранее вроде бы все договорились, что мол это нормальные вопросы.
- Да и вообще это просто интересно. Ну положим не всем, но мне да.

Comment: Проблема в том, что этот вопрос — не code-golf.

Comment: @andreymal Ну да, соревнования со свободными правилами.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Я не до конца понимаю Вашу точку зрения. О каких _"таких"_ вопросах в Вашем ответе идёт речь? Вам указали на то, что [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1105132/339283) — не [tag:code-golf], и Вы согласились. Правильно ли я тогда понимаю, что Вы поддерживаете _"соревнования со свободными правилами"_?

Comment: @nomnoms12 yes!

Comment: если правила свободные - то это не соревнования :)

Comment: @Grundy popularity contest ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica у popularity contest тоже есть [требования](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info)

Answer (score 0):

Начать хочу с того, что прошу всех общаться как профессионалы и не переходить на личности. А теперь по делу.

1. SO - не форум, как бы многим этого не хотелось. Это, в первую очередь, база знаний. Вопрос должен быть конкретным, чтобы на него можно было дать ответ.
2. [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [code-golf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) появились как следствие того, что обычные вопросы слишком скучные казались. Решили разнообразить себе времяпровождение. Сообщество, в целом, поддержало.
3. Пример вопроса из обсуждения слишком общий. Множество плюсов не означают, что вопрос полезен в копилке базы знаний. Все мы видели комментарии (и многие так считают), что нет смысла давать полный ответ участнику, если он ничего сам не попытался сделать. Он ничему не научится. Также и тут, подобные вопросы интересны, это весёлое времяпровождение, бесспорно. Но с точки зрения базы знаний весьма неоднозначны.

   Вопросы подобные я раньше видел на форумах для разработчиков. Удалять их не хочется. Поэтому, мне видится, лучшее решение привести эти вопросы к формату соревнований и, если понадобиться, пересмотреть требования к [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и/или [code-golf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) (когда есть чёткие рамки; [пример вопроса)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/926927/15479).

Comment: _"лучшее решение привести эти вопросы к формату соревнований"_. А если это невозможно? Лично мне слабо верится, что [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1105132/339283) можно будет к такому формату привести.

Comment: _"SO - не форум... Вопросы подобные я раньше видел на форумах... Удалять их не хочется"_ Почему их не хочется удалять?

Comment: @nomnoms12 не подвести, да. Поэтому, либо закрыть, либо пересмотреть формат соревнования.

Comment: @nomnoms12 жалко потраченных сил участников.

Answer (score 0):

Я недолюбливаю соревнования, но всё же они достаточно конкретны, чтобы пусть со скрипом, но всё-таки вписываться в формат базы знаний. Если опираться на [«большой» код-гольф](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), к соревнованиям применяются такие требования:

- **чёткое определение**, что нужно сделать;
- **критерий победы**, по которому будет выбрано лучшее решение.

В обсуждаемом здесь вопросе на первый взгляд вроде бы конкретно по пунктам указано, что нужно сделать (наивно предположу, что это и привело в заблуждение проверяющих в очереди проверок), но дальше присутствует такой текст:

> Приемлемы **любые другие** текстовые эффекты, эффекты трансформации, **абсолютно любые эффекты** анимации **без ограничений**. А также по **своему** сценарию [...]

То есть вопрос прямым текстом **отказывается** от чёткого определения задачи. А критериев победы там и не было никогда.

То есть **это не соревнование**, и он [никогда не задумывался быть соревнованием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1104611/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8/1104653#comment1904238_1104653):

> У меня предложение: Откройте новую тему Текстовые эффекты, с **не жесткими** рамками, типа анимация теста, эффекты трансформации и т.д и т.п **порезвимся вволю** на карантине

Порезвимся вволю. Ну что за детский сад? Мы тут базу знаний составляем, а не с разговорами по душам чатимся. Я тоже сижу на самоизоляции, но резвлюсь в более подходящих для этого местах (̶в̶р̶е̶д̶н̶и̶ч̶а̶ю̶ ̶в̶ ̶к̶о̶м̶м̶е̶н̶т̶а̶р̶и̶я̶х̶)̶

---

Stack Overflow — это **база знаний** в формате вопросов и ответов. Конкретный вопрос — конкретный ответ. Пользователь, ищущий решение своей проблемы, должен иметь возможность вбить ключевые слова своего вопроса и найти релевантный ответ в этой базе знаний.

Если хочется поделиться примерами всех возможных способов анимировать слово в svg или просто в вебе, следует создать отдельные вопросы с «практичными» заголовками наподобие «Как сделать [такую-то] анимацию слова». Пример хорошего вопроса — [«Как сделать анимацию заливки текста двумя цветами»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1104611): в вопросе чётко (ну, почти) указана решаемая задача; при этом он *не слишком узкий*, что допускает некоторую вариативность ответа в рамках разумного и позволяет ему быть полезным другим людям со *слегка* отличающейся задачей; в ответах перечислены разные подходы её решения в рамках установленных критериев (впрочем, я бы добавил упоминание градиента в заголовок).

В подобного вида вопросах, во-первых, по заголовку будет сразу ясно, о чём речь; во-вторых, в ответах может быть предложено несколько вариантов решения одной и той же задачи (в том числе в будущем, на более новых технологиях); в третьих, другие подобные вопросы можно будет отмечать как дубликаты, ссылаясь на основной вопрос; в-четвёртых, человек, желая сделать анимацию конкретного вида, без проблем через поиск найдёт нужный ему вопрос в базе знаний по заголовку.

Обсуждаемый здесь вопрос отказывается от конкретных критериев; **здесь всё свалено в одну кучу.**

Если всё свалено в одну кучу, становится фактически невозможно отмечать похожие вопросы как дубликаты.

Где-то упоминали, что большинство посещений SO идёт из поисковых систем. Если пользователь попытается загуглить вопрос по конкретной анимации и наткнётся на сабж, он рискует не долистать до интересующего ответа, утонув в куче других ответов, не имеющих отношения к проблеме пользователя, или просто случайно проглядеть его. А если автор ответа не потрудится добавить краткое текстовое описание, то его ответ в поисковиках и вовсе не будет найден и не прочитается никем кроме нескольких постоянных участников. То есть по сути **сайт становится менее релевантен.**

Так как люди уже написали свои ответы в общей куче, весьма маловероятно, что они решат оформить их в пригодном для пользования стиле «вопрос-ответ», а значит множество полезных примеров так и останется валяться в куче, в которую никто никогда (почти) не полезет. **Сайт лишается части полезных вопросов**, потому ответы на них осели в этой куче (конечно, можно понадеяться, что кто-нибудь их всё-таки создаст в будущем, но не факт).

Говорят, подобные ответы даже в общей куче всё равно якобы помогут человеку научиться и вынести полезные знания. Однако хороший обучающий материал должен разъяснять всё во всех подробностях, смысл существования определённых подходов и техник, границы применимости и так далее. Ответы в обсуждаемом вопросе в основном ограничиваются кратким описанием, а некоторые ответы не имеют описания вовсе. **Из груды слабо связанных примеров не получится вынести ничего кроме бездумного их копипаста** (и хорошо если человек хотя бы надумает прочитать какой-нибудь учебник). <sub>*(На самом деле эта проблема касается и многих других ответов на ruSO, но к счастью находятся люди, которые просят в комментариях дополять ответы пояснениями, а значит это не считается нормой и можно надеяться на светлое будущее.)*</sub>

Если после прочтения предыдущего абзаца появилось желание создать вопрос вида «Как делаются анимации текста в svg», то такой вопрос тоже слишком общий. Достаточно полный или подробный ответ на такой вопрос потребует немаленькой статьи [или даже книги](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9303), но, как гласит [справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> Вопросы должны быть узкими — если для ответа на вопрос требуется написать книгу, он явно не для этого ресурса.

В итоге получается, что люди «порезвились», а вопрос с ответами лежат мёртвым грузом в базе знаний, мешаются в результатах поиска и никакого толку не дают.

## Не надо так. <sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub>

Я считаю, что вопрос должен быть закрыт как слишком общий (как минимум до удаления «абсолютно любых» критериев из текста вопроса), а ответы следует разнести по отдельным, более конкретным вопросам с более релевантными для поиска формулировками (если их возможно сформулировать).

Кроме того, подобные вопросы подают вредный пример новичкам, которые тоже могут начать создавать сомнительные вопросы в стиле «сделайте чё-нибудь», а в случае их закрытия начнут возмущаться «а почему им можно, а мне нельзя». И это, наверное, даже ещё более серьёзная причина для закрытия, чем всё описанное выше. Теория разбитых окон и всё такое.

Всё написанное выше в какой-то мере относится и к новогодним конкурсам. Я с января стабильно [каждые две недели голосую за их закрытие](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0q91.png), пусть это ни к чему и не приводит, да.

---

Вообще, мне кажется, что в дополнение к SO было бы неплохо иметь какой-нибудь форум на свободные темы, на котором сообщество могло бы «порезвиться вволю на карантине». Тогда данной проблемы в принципе не возникло бы. База знаний — отдельно, развлечения — отдельно. Развлечения это хорошо, если они не в базе знаний.

Comment: По существу ответить нечего, минусуют на эмоциях, ай-яй-яй

Comment: @Sevastopol' иногда могу подзабыть, но через пару дней обязательно вспоминаю и навёрстываю упущенное.

Comment: @Sevastopol' могу бота для этого дела написать :)